# C++ Dangling Pointers and Memory Leaks

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm having a hard time understanding how to tell between dangling pointers and memory leaks. I have a few questions on a recent assignment that are puzzling me, and after reading into it, I am still puzzled. I don't want someone to do my homework for me, I want to be able to understand why something is what it is, if that makes sense.

So, the homework:

---

Given the declarations:

```cpp
int *ptrA, *ptrB;
```

Tell whether each code segment below results in a memory leak, a dangling pointer, or neither. Draw pictures to help.

1. I'm guessing that this is fine, as `ptrA` is already pointing to something in memory, so this one is neither a dangling pointer or a memory leak.

```cpp
ptrA = new int;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
ptrB = ptrA;
```

2. I'm guessing that this is a dangling pointer because 345 was deallocated from memory, so `ptrB` points to nothing.

```cpp
ptrA = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
ptrB = ptrA;
delete ptrA;
```

3. This is where I'm complete lost. Does the last line mean that the pointer is pointing to another pointer? Not sure what the implications of this would be.

```cpp
ptrA = new int;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
*ptrB = *ptrA;
```

4. Like the previous question, I'm not sure what pointing to a pointer means, or if I even understand what this is achieving.

```cpp
ptrA = new int;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrB = *ptrA;
```

5. I know this is a dangling pointer, but I don't know why. Is it because the pointer is pointing to a local variable that went out of scope when the function finished?

```cpp
ptrA = LocationOfAge();
```

where function `LocationOfAge` is defined as:

```cpp
int *LocationOfAge() {
  int age = 21;
  return &age;
}
```

---

Thanks for anyone willing to help.

Comment: A question should contain one question. This contains five. They are tightly related, but you may be pushing it. `ptrB = ptrA;` in 1 just leaked `ptrB`. The address it held is gone, so there is no way to delete what it held.

Comment: @user4581301 A comment should not contain an answer :)

Comment: For every `new` draw a box. For every delete cross the box out (you don't have those). For every `a = b` (where there are no stars) draw a line from a variable to a box. For every `*x = y` write y inside the box. When you have a box with no variables pointing at it you have a leak. If you have a pointer that does not point at a box you have a dangling pointer.

Comment: It's only 1/5 of an answer.

Comment: Quick comment on the difference between dangling pointers and memory leaks: they are (almost) opposite. A dangling pointer points to a piece of memory that was allocated, but was deallocated. Possibly reallocated to something else. A memory leak is memory to which no pointer in the active program points. (There May be pointers to it in other leaked objects.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The rules of the game:

- For every `new Type` draw a box. Put a question in the box (you don't know what is in there).
- For every `delete p` cross out the box pointed to by `p`.
- For every `a = b` (where there are no stars) draw a line from variable `a` to a box `b`.
- For every `*x = y` write `y` inside the box pointed at by `x`.
- For every `*x = *y` read the content of the box `y` and put a copy in `x`

The result:

- When you have a box with no variables pointing at it you have a leak.
- If you have a pointer that does not point at a box (or a crossed out box) you have a dangling pointer.

The first problem:

```
ptrA = new int;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
ptrB = ptrA;
```

Lets do this line by line:

> ptrA = new int;

```
// Part 1 has a new so draw a box
              *********
              *   ?   *
              *********

// Part 2 assignment to variable add a line
ptrA -------> *********
              *   ?   *
              *********
```

> ptrB = new int;

```
// Part 3 has a new so draw another box
ptrA -------> *********
              *   ?   *
              *********

              *********
              *   ?   *
              *********

// Part 4 assignment to variable add a line

ptrA -------> *********
              *   ?   *
              *********

ptrB -------> *********
              *   ?   *
              *********
```

> *ptrA = 345;

```
ptrA -------> *********
              *  345  *
              *********

ptrB -------> *********
              *   ?   *
              *********
```

> ptrB = ptrA;

```
ptrA -------> *********
        |     *  345  *
        |     *********
        |
ptrB ----     *********
              *   ?   *
              *********
```

Seems like you have a leaked box. i.e. There is a box with no variable pointing at it.

Comment: Beautifully explained, super simple!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I'm guessing that this is fine, as ptrA is already pointing to something in memory, so this one is neither a dangling pointer or a memory leak.

Yeah but now `ptrB` points to it too, and you have no way of freeing the thing that `ptrB` pointed to before.

So that's a leak.

> 2. I'm guessing that this is a dangling pointer because 345 was deallocated from memory, so ptrB points to nothing.

Correct.

> 3. Does the last line mean that the pointer is pointing to another pointer?

No, it gives <the thing that `ptrB` points to> the value of <the thing that `ptrA` points to>. No changes to the pointers involved, only `int` assignment.

> 4. Like the previous question, I'm not sure what pointing to a pointer means, or if I even understand what this is achieving.

The second `new int` is leaked, because the thing that used to point to it (`ptrB`) now points to a *third* `new int` and the former can no longer be freed.

> 5. I know this is a dangling pointer, but I don't know why. Is it because the pointer is pointing to a local variable that went out of scope when the function finished?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent making all homework, your first assumption is wrong.

```
1. ptrA = new int;
2. ptrB = new int;
3. *ptrA = 345;
4. ptrB = ptrA;
```

In line 1, ptrA creates a new integer (bytes are allocated), in line 2 ptrB allocates bytes. Than in 3, the memory allocated in 1 is filled, which is OK.
However, in line 4, ptrB is overwritten with the address of 3, this means the original addres of ptrB is not reachable anymore. And thus there is a memory leak, because the bytes allocated for the integer PtrB by line 2 can never be accessed anymore, since there is no pointer pointing to it.

It's much easier if you write a drawing, by using arrows for pointers and a box with either a ? for a declaration and a specific value when filled in. So it would look like:

```
1. ptrA -> [  ?  ]
2. ptrA -> [  ?  ], ptrB -> [ ? ]
3. ptrA -> [ 345 ], ptrB -> [ ? ]
4. ptrA -> [ 345 ] <- ptrB, [ ? ]
```

As you can see, the last box [ ? ] does not have any pointer pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take one question at a time.

```
ptrA = new int;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
ptrB = ptrA;
```

Here, it is a memory leak. Why? Because there is no `delete` first of all. Secondly, when you do `ptrB = ptrA;`, there is practically no way to call `delete` for the object that was pointed to by `ptrB` earlier.

```
ptrA = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
ptrB = ptrA;
delete ptrA;
```

This is an example of dangling pointer. Once `delete` is called on ptrA, the object pointed to by ptrA gets deallocated. So, ptrB points to a deallocated location whose behaviour is undefined. So, Dangling pointer!

```
ptrA = new int;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
*ptrB = *ptrA;
```

Here, there is memory leak simply because we are not calling `delete`. What we are doing is that we are creating two objects which are pointed by ptrA and ptrB respectively and both objects have value of 345. They still hold space in the heap. But how come both have the value of 345? Simple.

When you did `*ptrA = 345;`, it meant that the value of the object pointed to by ptrA should be set to 345.

When you did `*ptrB = *ptrA;`, it meant that the value of the object pointed by ptrB should be assigned with the value of the object pointed by ptrA.

This is the simple functioning of dereferencing operator.

```
ptrA = new int;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrA = 345;
ptrB = new int;
*ptrB = *ptrA;
```

This is similar to first one. In line 2, ptrB pointed to a dynamically allocated object. After execution of Line 4, ptrB points to entirely new object. So, there is no way to deallocate the object whose memory was allocated at line 2. So, Memory Leak!

```
int *LocationOfAge() {
    int age = 21;
    return &age;
}
```

Here, `age` is a local variable which will die once the function ends. So, any pointer to that local variable leads to undefined behaviour. So, Dangling Pointer!

Comment: From the question it sounds like `*ptrB = *ptrA;` in 3 had the asker scratching their head. Might as well throw them a bone and give them a quick explaination of the dereference operator. For five you should call it what it is: Dangling pointer.

Comment: Oh! There we go. Ignore the last bit.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your suggestion. I have included your point.